# How to round up a value in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to round up the value. For example,

```
23.0f / 10.0f = 2.3f -> round up to 3
11.0f / 10.0f = 1.1f -> round up to 2
15.0f / 10.0f = 1.5f -> round up to 2
67.0f / 10.0f = 6.7f -> round up to 7
1738.0f / 10.0 = 173.8f -> round up to 174
```

My current approach does not work, it rounds to the nearest integer instead of up:

```
public class Test {

    private static final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final float a = 23;
        final float b = 10;
        final float k = a / b;
        System.out.println(k);
        final float roundup = Math.round(k * 100) / 100;
        System.out.println(roundOff);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the desired behavior in Java?

Comment: Your examples do not match your description. "if the decimal point is above 1" should mean that 1.1 rounds to 1, because the decimal (1) is not above 1. Do you perhaps mean you'd like to round **up** if the decimal is above **zero**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Math` library, do not reinvent the wheel.

```
private int roundUp(float value){
    return (int) Math.ceil(value);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to either the value to `int`.

Comment: Mark the question as duplicate. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: neither valueOf nor parseInt accept double which is returned from math.ceil

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it's not a duplicate of the linked post. The linked post is concerned with integer arithmetics.

Comment: @IłyaBursov cast works

Comment: @Turing85 The answers to the duplicate question more than adequately address the current question.